# BenQ Monitor USB Ports Not Working

Tags: usb, display, peripherals

The USB ports (hub) on the left side of my BenQ XL2730Z are not working when I plug my wired mouse and wireless keyboard into them.

I have connected my Macbook Pro to the monitor using the USB A/B cable that comes with the monitor and then plugged in an Evoluent ergonomic wired mouse and a Microsoft ergonomic wireless keyboard to the USB ports on the side of the monitor. The red light on the bottom of the mouse turns on but the mouse does not respond when moved and typing on the keyboard does nothing.

According to BenQ support (although I don't have much faith in them), the ports on the side of the monitor do not provide enough power and therefore can only be used for data transfer (USB drives, cameras etc.) and not to power peripherals like mice and keyboard. I couldn't find this written in the user manual of the monitor anywhere.

Has anyone managed to get a mouse and keyboard to work by plugging them into the USB ports on the monitor?

Comment: Are these ports working with anything else? Did you try any vanilla USB keyboard? Any USB flash drives?

Comment: Note: BenQ response is obvious BS: mice and keyboards are the LEAST power-hungry peripherals among USB devices.

Comment: @AliChen I haven't yet. That's what I'll be doing tonight. I can understand why the wireless keyboard might not work, but the mouse is just a normal, wired mouse. And yes, that was my thinking exactly around the "power" excuse. I'm pretty sure it takes more power to spin a hard drive disk than it does to power a mouse.

Comment: Test the hub with an USB flash drive instead of mouse/keyboard. If it doesn't work with an USB stick, something is definitely broken (needn't be the hub, might be the cable, or even the port in the PC).

Comment: Got confirmation from BenQ support in the US as well as confirmed via a test that all peripherals are supported by the USB hub on the side of the screen. Turns out the screen was defective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the screen was defective and I confirmed (verbally and through experiment) that the USB ports on the side of the screen do in fact support mice and keyboards.

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem. I forgot to connect the USB cable from the monitor to the PC. The USB port on the Benq monitor is a USB hub. You have to connect a USB cable (should be supplied with the monitor) from the USB port on the computer to the input USB port on the monitor (the small square-like shaped port). Only then you can connect any USB devices to the USB ports on the monitor. I know your screen was defective. Just saying for others who might have the same problem as me.

Comment: Can verify that this fixed the issue for me for a BenQ PD3200U.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my SW320 (Germyn spec). My mouse, however, is a 'power-hungry' Roccat Nyth with LED illumination options turned on. It worked for some time nicely, but eventually it freezed.

I disconnected the mouse, then plugged it in again, and it kept working. However, this is something I need to do every now and then, i.e., at least once in a week.

I agree with you that BenQ's answer is BS, as a USB 3.0 interface by specifiaction needs to provide enough power to feed my mouse, and, for sure, a standard mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I have a BenQ PD3200U and it took me several tries to realize that it has upstream and downstream USB ports. The downstream ports won't work unless one of the upstream ports is connected to the computer.

Also, the upstream ports on the PD3200U are all USB 3.0 B ports. (USB A is the common flat one; USB 2.0 B is the squarish one; USB 3.0 B is shaped like a stone temple.)

https://www.benq.com/en-us/monitor/professional/pd3200u/spec.html